# For which $a$ does $e^{ian}$ have a limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that if $a$ is a real number $\notin 2π\mathbb Q$ then the sequence $e^{ian}$ cannot have a limit.

I'm pretty sure some more general density fact can help here.

Comment: I don't have limits :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute the distance between $e^{ian}$ and $e^{ia(n + 1)}$; you'll find that it's

$$|e^{ian} - e^{ia(n + 1)}| = |e^{ian}|\cdot |1 - e^{ia}| = |1 - e^{ia}|$$

Now if a sequence of complex numbers converges, the distance between successive terms tends to $0$. When does this happen?

Comment: Are you assuming that $a$ is real?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's stated to be.

Comment: So it seems. The OP edited the post 3 hrs ago and made the change. +1

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication by $e^{ia}$ is a rotation of the complex plane by $a$ radians and $e^{(ian)} = (e^{ia})^n$ so it is a sequence of points on the unit circle each $a$ radians from the last. It cannot have a limit unless $a$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$ all of which give the same sequence.

Comment: That's mere handwaving here...